# how do I set up jasmine unit testing framework for a .net mvc solution?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I downloaded the jasmine-standalone zip and I'm able to run the sample tests provided in the zip.  However, I'm not sure how I would go about setting this up for ng2 components within a .NET MVC solution.  My solution has a standard .NET MVC setup with an ng2 folder which contains all of the ng2 related code.  The jasmine-standalone project has the following structure:

- lib
- spec
- src
- SpecRunner.html

I'm not clear on what structure or process I should use to adapt this to my MVC/ng2 hybrid project.

Comment: A lot of the configuration should be located in the karma.conf.js file. In that file, you can set the paths where the Jasmine tests are located, etc.

Comment: the latest standalone app download does not have a karma.config.js file.  does the standalone download use the default supported structure whereas karma.config.js is used for custom configurations?
https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure. I'm basing my information off of Angular's quickstart project, which comes with a karma.conf.js file. I'm not sure if it should be there in your case.

Comment: Sorry I'm somewhat inexperienced in js unit testing.  I was under the impression that Jasmine and Karma were separate unit frameworks but for the Jasmine test setup I'm describing you're referring to a karma.config.js file.  Is that a typo or are Jasmine and Karma somehow inter-related or commonly used together?

Comment: From what I understand: Jasmine is the testing framework. It defines how the tests are written/what methods are available to assert conditions/etc. Karma is a test runner. It takes in tests written in a testing framework (IE: Jasmine) as input, runs them, and displays the results of the tests in a webpage.

Comment: The Jasmine team provides the following github page where I can download a jasmine-standalone zip: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases. This has lib, spec, src dirs + a SpecRunner.html page. So if all my ng2 code is in an ng2 dir and I want to use Jasmine to test my ng2 then should I create a "tests" subdir under ng2 and then include all of the contents of the jasmine-standalone zip here? I'm trying to figure out the proper/common way of integrating Jasmine into an ng2 project.